# I want to change back and foward between two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm need to change between two deferent layout, i have firs layout .xml file whit two buttons and depending of the button i need to change the layout to a new one and also i need to be able to return to the main layout like using the back button or something like that.

I was trying to change the layouts using setContenview but i keep losing all the buttons and edittext that i previously define.

Comment: Let's get one thing clarified first. You set a new layout and say that you're losing previously defined buttons. Do you mean losing the buttons etc you define in this new layout, or the ones which were shown on original layout?

Comment: The ones in the original layout, this happends when i try to come back to the original layout

Comment: Check out this great tutorial on View Flipper .. It is sure to help ... http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634

Answer (score 3):

See ViewFlipper: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html.

You make a ViewFlipper the root view of your layout, then add both layouts to ViewFlipper, and you can simply flip between them.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a clear advantage of using ViewFlipper compared to using setContentView?

Comment: Well, other than the fact that ViewFlipper (and its cousin ViewSwitcher) are expressly designed for this purpose, the layout inflation is basically done only once at creation time, so it is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, was wondering it was more likely for separating layout from code but this gave some insight I didn't think of.